# Computer randomly shuts down and displays blinking screen

Tags: freeze, shutdown, reboot

I am having issues with my PC. It randomly shuts down and screen starts blinking. It happens completely randomly and I didn't notice any pattern. Sometimes it might work properly for a week and sometimes it starts to shut down every 10 minutes. It doesn't matter what work I do it still may shut down even when I leave it in idle state.

[image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu1hu.png)

Specs are:

```
CPU: i5-4570
RAM: 8GB
HDD: 1TB
Video card: AMD Radeon HD 8570
```

Things I tried so far:

Initially I thought that this is a video card problem, so I Uninstalled/Installed viedo card drivers. It didn't helped. Then I removed video card and started using Intel HD Graphics 4600. It also didn't helped. Then I removed HDD and booted in with Ubuntu Live usb. Issue still happened. Then I thought that one of RAMs might be damaged(I have 4x2gb - 8Gb total), so I removed all RAM and started to boot with one RAM at a time to see which one is damaged. With each of RAM issue reproduced.

I don't know what to do next, so I am writing here to seek your advice

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've checked the obvious like ensuring your fans are operational and the unit isn't overheating, one thing to consider is uneven power. Something else plugged into the same circuit could be drawing too much power (space heaters are notorious for causing this kind of issue)...even a small voltage drop can cause the unit to shutdown.  Try plugging the PC into a UPS (even just a small cheap one) and monitor for a while. But another possibility, and more likely answer, is an issue with the motherboard … hope that is not the case.

Comment: thank you for response. I already plugged PC into UPS, but issue still occurred, so I don't think voltage drop is the issue. I agree with the assumption that it might be motherboard, but I don't know how to check/fix it :(